Center one of four flex children, grow remaining to fill space
I have a flex container of 4 children. I want the 1st and 3rd child to have a %, min and max widths. The 2nd and 4th child to grow to fill remaining space. But the 3rd child needs to also be centered at all times.
I've tried justify-self and margins. I don't want to position it absolute as this means it won't interact with the 1st child once the 2nd child has shrunk to 0.
